# Excel - Calculating duration between two time frames

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This formula works great if the beginning time is in AM and the end time is in PM:

```
=TEXT(C3-B3,"[m]")&" minutes"
```

In my case I have a time frame that begins in PM and ends in AM(the next day).
I get the following total "-571 ."

What would I need to add to my formula (or maybe a different formula for this scenario) to calculate the total correctly?

[image]

Updated Post:

[image]

Formula:

```
=TEXT((C4+(C3<B4))-B3,"[m]")&" minutes"
```

Calculating the following: Begin: 4:29 PM   End: 6:58 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=TEXT((C3+(C3<B3))-B3,"[m]")&" minutes"
```

A boolean True in VBA can be considered -1 but on the worksheet it is 1. In either case, a False is zero. In this way, any time in column C that is less than the time in column B gets a day added to it.

[image]

Comment: The total comes out to 1456 minutes which would reflect about a 24 hour  cycle. This is too high.

Comment: Post your sample data together with the expected results. I've already retyped the supplied data once and as you can see, it seems to work out.

Comment: You're mashing up row 3 and row 4. Use one or the other. e.g. `=TEXT((C4+(C4<B4))-B4,"[m]")&" minutes"`